# Hightcharts - multiple pie charts on line chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Whats the best way to achieving the below chart using Highcharts library?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create additional `pie` charts as data labels:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var points = this.series[0].points,
                container;

            points.forEach(function(p) {
                container = p.dataLabel.div.querySelector('.dataLabelChart');

                Highcharts.chart(container, {
                    chart: {
                        margin: 0,
                        backgroundColor: 'transparent'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    series: [{
                        innerSize: 30,
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        type: 'pie',
                        data: [1, 2, 3]
                    }],
                    legend: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
},
series: [{
    dataLabels: {
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        enabled: true,
        useHTML: true,
        formatter: function() {
            return '<div class="dataLabelChart" id="' + this.point.index + '"></div>'
        }
    },
    ...
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/y46ubx1L/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.scatter.dataLabels.formatter

Comment: Thanks. This is I was looking for